# Retrieve SQS message content from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs

I am sending a message from AWS SQS and want to read the content of the message from a lambda function using boto3.

Can anyone please help and let me know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can associate an Amazon SQS queue as a **trigger** for an AWS Lambda function.

This means that the Lambda function will be automatically invoked by messages sent to the SQS queue.

The content of the SQS message will be passed to the Lambda function via the `event` field, together with message metadata.

See: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)

Comment: Yeah, i will trigger the lambda from SQS . Getting the SQS content which is stored in the event is what I am looking for. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I fetched the content from event parameter. Thanks for helping.